# Adding an id or data-testid to a reactDataGrid

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

For clarity we are using this reactDataGrid, (https://reactdatagrid.io/)

Does anyone know if there any way to add an id or data-testid to the grid? I cannot find anything in the documentation and I I have tried anything I can think of. I unfortunately need to add ids because of testing. Any help is much appreciated!

```
 <ReactDataGrid
    treeColumn="description"
    licenseKey="..."
    style={gridStyle}
    columns={columns}
    data-id="workPlease"
  />

 <ReactDataGrid
    treeColumn="description"
    licenseKey="..."
    style={gridStyle}
    columns={columns}
    data-testid="workPlease"
  />

 <ReactDataGrid
    treeColumn="description"
    licenseKey="..."
    style={gridStyle}
    columns={columns}
    id="workPlease"
  />
```

Comment: I've found this a problem myself.  RTL doesn't seem to read data-testid on components unlike Enzyme.  It only reads them on elements.

The solution is to wrap the grid in a <div data-testid>...</div> or find another way to access the component like a classname or id property.